# Laptop dies after connecting to an adapter

Tags: laptop, hp-pavilion

I have an HP Pavilion laptop, and a few days ago it's battery was low so I plugged in the power adapter cord to charge it. As soon as I connected the cord the laptop died.

I have a power surge protector to protect it from any voltage fluctuation, so it can't be that.

I showed it to a service centre and they told me that the laptop's motherboard was damaged. They didn't tell me why the motherboard got damaged, but I would like to know.

I would like to know why my laptop's motherboard got damaged and how to protect a laptop from this type of accident in the future.

Comment: Was there anything possibly wrong with the power cord or laptop? like things hanging out/cracked/broken? Had you dropped it recently, or spilled anything? Is this an HP-brand power cord, or a third-party one? Also, are you sure you're plugging it into a wall outlet with the correct frequency (I think the US usually uses 60Hz, while the rest of the world uses 120Hz?)

Comment: Was the laptop on when you plugged it in?

Comment: Everyone uses 50-60 hz. Its the voltage that's different. SMPS generally work with different voltages with no issue tho.

Answer (score 0):

If the "service center" said "Its mother board damage"

Its probably defective, and dont want you to ask them to replace it...

## Go ahead and ask them to replace it.